# remove duplicates delimited string batch

Tags: batch-file

Done a quick search, but can't get to the bottom of this one. I want to remove any duplicates from a string with values separated by commas. e.g.

```
set _str=1,2,3,1,5,4,2
```

Processing of this would populate a new variable with the 'un-duped' list. e.g.

```
echo %_finalstr%
```

Would produce:

1,2,3,5,4

Added complication _str can be any number of components (i.e. it could be 1 value, it could be 200). It could also be null. No problems with special chars though - it will all be in the format of number, comma, number, comma etc. The values could also be in any order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "string=1,2,3,5,4,2"
CALL :process
SET "string=1,2,3,5,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,107,221,3,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,13,2,1"
CALL :process
SET "string="
CALL :process
SET "string=3"
CALL :process
SET "string=3,3"
CALL :process
GOTO :eof

:process
SET "newstring=,"
IF DEFINED string FOR %%a IN (%string%) DO (SET "newstring=!newstring:,%%a,=,!%%a,")
SET "newstring=%newstring:~1,-1%"
ECHO oldstring:%string%:
ECHO newstring:%newstring%:
GOTO :EOF
```

Another way, with inbuilt demonstration

edit --- explanation.

Set `newstring` to a single comma. This ensures `newstring` both starts and ends with a comma.

The `for` iterates through each element in the string; the commas are seen as separators.

For each element `n` found, replaced any `,n,` with `,`  then add `n,` to the end.

Result: list of unique elements, surrounded by `,` - so remove the first and last characters and done.

Note that `delayedexpansion` and the use of `!` facilitates this method, but

```
IF DEFINED string FOR %%a IN (%string%) DO CALL SET "newstring=%%newstring:,%%a,=,%%%%a,"
```

could be used regardless of `delayedexpansion` state.

The quotes are for terminal-space-suppression, following standard practice.

Comment: Ooh - very nice, unexpected solution.

Comment: Perfect. Fantastically elegant. Thanks Magoo! I'm just trying to figure how the Set newstring part works at end of the if statement...

Comment: This solution modify the original order of the input elements. Also, the `IF DEFINED string` part is not necessary, because a `FOR` with an empty set execute nothing...

Comment: @Aacini : you're probably right about the `if defined` - a hangover from a previous version. As for the `original` order - well, depends. Try reading the result-string in reverse - it is then the reverse-order of elements in the starting string...

Comment: @Magoo: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641835/remove-duplicates-delimited-string-batch/26660417#26660417) below...

Answer (score 2):

A way :

```
@echo off
set "$str=1,2,3,1,5,4,2"

for %%a in (%$str%) do set "##%%a=%%a"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set ##') do set "$FinalStr=!$FinalStr!,%%a"
set "$FinalStr=!$FinalStr:~1!"
echo !$FinalStr!
```

Comment: This does not numerically sort the numbers if the widths vary: 10 will sort before 8.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to modify so that it does sort. BTW - I already gave you +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below preserve the original order of the elements, as requested by the OP:

> ```
> set _str=1,2,3,1,5,4,2
> ```
>
> Processing of this would populate a new variable with the 'un-duped' list. e.g.
>
> ```
> echo %_finalstr%
> ```
>
> Would produce:
>
> 1,2,3,5,4

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set _str=1,2,3,1,5,4,2
REM set "_str="

set "_finalstr=,"
for %%a in (%_str%) do if "!_finalstr:,%%a,=!" equ "!_finalstr!" set "_finalstr=!_finalstr!%%a,"
set "_finalstr=%_finalstr:~1,-1%"
echo Oldstring: "%_str%"
echo Newstring: "%_finalstr%"
```

Comment: This is a great extension of the original problem. As it happens, the order doesn't matter in my specific case, but this is handy if it does.... :)